# Can I see if/when someone opens Messages on my Mac?

Tags: iphone, messages

I'm concerned my roommate is looking at my text messages via the Messages app on my computer. Is there a way to know if/when the Messages app is opened on the computer? Maybe a notification or email to my iPHone?

Comment: Or maybe password lock your machine & avoid the entire issue in the first place?? If your roommate needs to use the machine, give him his own account or make him use Guest.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of applications which let you create macros and scripts and trigger them in various ways. I have the most experience with [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/), so that's what I used for the example macro below. However, as Tetsujin commented, simply password protecting your computer probably makes more sense from a security standpoint; there isn't really any reason someone else should have access to your account.

[image: Keyboard Maestro macro]

Answer (score 0):

When you open Messages.app, it often leaves a timestamped indication in the "Diagnostic and Usage Data" and "System Log" reports in your Console app (located in `/Applications/Utilities`) which can be found by selecting them and entering "Messages" in the search box at the upper right of the window, as shown here:

[image: Diagnostic and Usege Data showing messages.app entry in Console]
[image: System Log showing messages.app entry in Console]

Alternatively, an inexpensive app like Time Sink ([App Store link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/time-sink/id404363161?mt=12)) can record a timestamped log of all programs and documents opened on your computer. However, if your roommate is crafty enough, they can just quit Time Sink before doing their evil deeds, then restart it again when they're done, preventing it from recording their actions. However, if they don't know it's there or what it does, this will show if they were on your computer when you weren't home.

Finally, the free app ControlPlane ([website](https://www.controlplaneapp.com)) can run silently in the background and execute scripts when specified applications are open. However, it's a bit technical and intricate to set up, and you'd need to write your own Applescript or BASH script for ControlPlane to run to log the application opening.

Comment: Great solutions. Y'all really know your stuff!! :)

Comment: You have to know these things when you're a king. ;-)